# how to restart android avd?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, reboot

i want to catch the BOOT_COMPLETED action in my program, how to restart the AVD??
thanks in advance.....

```
package com.alex.app.testsysaction;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("receiver", "system reboot completed.......");
    }
}
```

the AndrdoiManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.alex.app.testsysaction"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This was so easy you must have tried it once restarting your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install application on AVD.

Close it and then restart it again manually.It will catch reboot action